# Bluetooth Mesh Module

Tags: communication, wireless

So I would like to design a device that allows me to send instructions to different devices (each containing a HC-06 Module). I would like to ask if it would be ideal to use a Bluetooth Mesh?
This is the Module I plan on getting:
https://www.silabs.com/products/wireless/bluetooth/bluetooth-low-energy-modules/bgm13p-bluetooth-module

Comment: Depends on what "instructions" you're trying to send. Is there something preventing you from using another wireless interface? In other words, why are you choosing Bluetooth instead of something else? i.e. Zigbee, RFID, etc.?

Comment: Well because I will be using my mobile phone/computer as the transmitter. So I won't be able to use Zigbee and RFID right?

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like you're limited to some resources. Yes, there are a very small amount of phones and PC peripherals that have Zigbee interfacing. Same goes for RFID. There's also WiFi well. The decisions are yours to make. The way you transmit information is dependent on how you do it, like writing a script that is capable of sending information to devices. For instance, there are some Python libraries that can help you out (i.e. Pybluez). Scilabs is a good partner of ours. They usually have software where you can interface with your device and have a lot of resources for tutorials.

Comment: Sorry I haven't used a Bluetooth Module with the Mesh feature. Does it require the devices to be paired to it?

Comment: You could use mesh technology, but how many devices do you plan on using? Maybe just connecting a couple peripherals to a central is enough?

Comment: I am planning to connect at least 10 devices. But if I want smart phones to connect to it, I won't be able to use it right?