# Bluetooth Mesh and Bluetooth Broadcasting

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I have been reading up about Bluetooth recently and I just want to know if it is correct to say that all Bluetooth 5.0 have the broadcasting feature?  Is that the broadcasting feature also found in Bluetooth Mesh?

Comment: This is the *third* question you have asked about this in the past two days https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/433672/bluetooth-mesh-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to know about bluetooth low energy (BLE).

A broadcaster is a device that sends out advertising packets, but does not allow a connection from a central device. This is a basic feature that is part of **all** BLE versions.

Bluetooth Mesh is building on top of BLE and the broadcasting feature is not making much sense on this higher abstraction level. Although, technically, you can say that the broadcasting feature is part of Bluetooth Mesh.

Comment: Ohh okay, thank you so much!!